# Adding a condition to left outer join based on other condition - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to add a condition to the "on" part of a left outer join depending on other condition. I am trying to use "case when" but SQL Server 2008 throws a syntax error (it is not happy with equality signs). It might be easy, sorry for that, but I really couldn't see how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@declare @timeMode int = 2;
...
...
select *
from #AllPeriods ap 
left outer join #results r on ap.p1= r.p1 
                           and ap.p2 = r.p2 
                           and DATEDIFF(S,ap.StartPeriod, r.StartPeriod) = 0 
                           and 
                             case 
                                when @timeMode != 4 
                                   then DATEDIFF(s,ap.EndPeriod, r.EndPeriod) = -1 
                                   else DATEDIFF(s,ap.EndPeriod, r.EndPeriod) = 0 
                             end
```

Comment: CASE is an expression. It is used to return a scalar value. It cannot be used the way you are trying to in your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case`, but SQL Server doesn't recognize a boolean expression as a viable option.  So, here is one way to use `case`:

```
from #AllPeriods ap left outer join
     #results r
     on ap.p1 = r.p1 and 
        ap.p2 = r.p2 and 
        DATEDIFF(second, ap.StartPeriod, r.StartPeriod) = 0 and 
        DATEDIFF(second, ap.EndPeriod, r.EndPeriod) = (case when @timeMode <> 4 then -1 else 0 end)
```

However, the `case` is not needed.  You can just use `OR`:

```
from #AllPeriods ap left outer join
     #results r
     on ap.p1 = r.p1 and 
        ap.p2 = r.p2 and 
        DATEDIFF(second, ap.StartPeriod, r.StartPeriod) = 0 and 
        ((@timeMode <> 4 and DATEDIFF(second, ap.EndPeriod, r.EndPeriod) = -1) or
         (@timeMode = 4 and DATEDIFF(second, ap.EndPeriod, r.EndPeriod) = 0)
        )
```

Note:  This isn't quite right if `@timeMode could be`NULL`.